# Meta: Tag synonym request: [tag:votes] -> [tag:voting]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The following tags need to be merged as synonyms:

- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) - 1 question, no tag description. Needs to be made a synonym of
- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) - 41 questions, no tag description.

These two tags have exactly the same meaning. Neither have a tag wiki, so they cannot be distinguished.

The [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) tag should be merged into the [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) tag because [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) has more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we need the synonym, I just removed the 'votes' tag from it's one question - that question already used the 'voting' tag as well anyway.

The tag cleanup script will auto-delete the other tag next time it is run.

Comment: Sounds good. It works either way.